# cannot write to newly created table in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, create-table

in our Azure SQL Service  db we had a table App_Tracking that is/was used to track user actions. We needed to increase the size of the log buffer so I first copied over all the records to an archive table that was defined using this SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[App_Tracking_Nov20_2015]( 
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[UserID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, 
[App_Usage] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL, 
[Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL )
```

Then using SQL Management Studio 2012 I recreated the original table using :Drop/Create script Generation:

```
USE [tblAdmin] GO 
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[App_Tracking] Script Date: 11/21/2015 11:42:01 AM ******/ 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[App_Tracking] GO 
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[App_Tracking] Script Date: 11/21/2015 11:42:01 AM ******/ 
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[App_Tracking]( 
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[UserID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, 
[App_Usage] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL, 
[Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey_ 7c88841f-aaaa-bbbb-cccc- c26fe6a5720e] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
 [ID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ) 
GO
```

this is the automated drop/create that SMS2012 creates for you

I then updated statistics on App_Admin using EXEC sp_updatestats

The gotcha is that I can no longer programattically add records to this table.

If I open App_Admin from manage.windowsazure.net and "open in Visual Studio" I can manually add a record to it. but if in SMS2012 I run the code

```
USE [tblAdmin] GO
UPDATE [dbo].[App_Tracking] SET 
[UserID] = 'e146ba22-930c-4b22-ac3c-15da47722e75' ,
[App_Usage] = 'search search: Bad Keyword: asdfadsfs' ,
[Timestamp] = '2015-11-20 20:00:18.700' 
GO
```

nothing gets updated but no error is thrown.

If programmatically I use

```
var adminContext = new App_AdminEntities(); 
string prunedAction = action.Length <= 4000 ? action : action.Trim().Substring (0, 4000); // insure we don't fault on overflow of too long a keyword list 
var appTracking = new App_Tracking 
{ 
UserID = userId, 
PP_Usage = prunedAction, 
Timestamp = DateTime.Now 
}; 
try { 
adminContext.App_Tracking.Add(APPTracking); 
adminContext.SaveChanges(); 
adminContext.Dispose(); 
}
```

I get an error thrown on SaveChanges (which is the .net SQL db function) What did I do wrong

Comment: Why do you create table **`[App_Tracking]`** and try to update **`[CR_Tracking]`**? You have 2 different tables

Comment: Error in code obfuscation updating and creating same table

Comment: OK so I found the problem.

it turns out I had not updated the EDMX file associated and thus the error was being thrown by internal entity validation - which is kindof hidden under the covers

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found the problem. it turns out I had not updated the EDMX file associated and thus the error was being thrown by internal entity validation - which is kindof hidden under the covers –